# I'm having trouble formatting ExtendReports timeStamp

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-extent-report

ExtentReports timeStamp, htmlReporter.config().setTimeStampFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Even though I set it this way, it still brings it in AP/PM format as seen in the picture. I need it in 0-23 hour format. I can never change it.

[timeStampPictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hepaM.jpg)

Comment: Please share the code what you have tried.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void startTestResultReport() throws Exception {
    //Raporun oluşturulacağı path ayarlama
    htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\testResults\\testResultReport.html");
    //Rapor her testte sıfırdan mı oluşturulsun yoksa varolanın üzerine mi eklensin
    htmlReporter.setAppendExisting(true);
    extent = new ExtentReports();
    extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
    // Dashboard açılı gelsin mi
    htmlReporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(false);
    // Raporun Title ayarlama
    htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Test Sonuç Raporu");
    // Rapor Adı
    htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Selenium OTF Testi");
    // Dashboard görüntülenme konumu(Bottom veya Top)
    htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.BOTTOM);
    // Raporun teması(Standart ve Siyah)
    htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
    // Komut dosyası ve stil sayfaları için protokol
    htmlReporter.config().setProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS);
    // Tarih biçimini ayarlama
    htmlReporter.config().setTimeStampFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

@nandan-a

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).